# XPath for first word?

Tags: html, xml, xpath, nsindexpath, domxpath

For this HTML / XML:

```
<div class="contentBlock">
  <h2> </h2>
  <h1></h1>
  <h1>DBS055 - single  module packages</h1>
</div>
```

I want to extract with XPath only `DBS055`, not the entire text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### XPath 2.0

```xpath
//h1[normalize-space()]/replace(normalize-space(),'^([\w\-]+).*', '$1')
```

will return all of the first words of the string values of those `h1` elements that have a non-space character in their string value.

### XPath 1.0

```xpath
substring-before(
  concat(
    normalize-space(
      translate(//h1[normalize-space()][1], ',;/.', ' ')), ' '), ' ')
```

approximates the more robust XPath 2.0 solution.  Expand `',;/.'` as necessary for various characters you consider to define word boundaries.

**Explanation:**

1. Select the first `h1` that has a non-whitespace-only string value.
2. Map all word boundary characters to spaces.
3. Append a space to cover single-word case.
4. Normalize spacing.
5. Return the substring before the first space.

Comment: it should not be h1[2]? the path igives me a result, but space only:(

Comment: No, the `[1]` is applied *after* the predicate, and you don't want to hardwire a `2` that would be data-dependent.   I've updated the XPaths to avoid any `h1` elements with white-space-only string values.   That should be more robust for you.

Comment: Thanks it works perfectly, if possible can you tell me where to look to learn these kinds of xpath statements, or some tutorials with explanations ?

Comment: I just ancountered a situation were : 
<div class="contentBlock">
  <h2> </h2>
  <h1></h1>
  <h1>DBS055 - single  module packages</h1>
</div

<div class="contentBlock">
  <h2> </h2>
  <h1></h1>
  <h1>DBS055, - single  module packages</h1>
</div
for example in the second part i have a ",", after DBS055, can i have a unique xpath for both cases?

Comment: Answer updated to make XPath 1.0 expression much more robust, including covering your new case that requires expansion of word boundary characters beyond just spaces.

Comment: Learning XPath:  Read [XML Path Language (XPath) Version 1.0](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/).